# Can RSA be used as a one-time pad for authentication?

Tags: rsa, provable-security

In the case of Smart Contracts, there are self-destruct functions for the contract which can only be run by the contract owner.  In many cases attackers have found a way to take over the contract owner.  Would it be possible to place an encrypted blob along with the public key and original plain-text message in the smart contract?  Then at time of required authentication (when the true author wants to destroy the contract) the original private key could provided for authentication.  Is there any crypto flaw in this?

Comment: Kevin, it appears you have (accidently?) created two user accounts. I suggest you take a look at [our help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and get your two accounts merged, so you can edit your post yourself :)

Comment: His first account was unregistered, no way to merge it.

Comment: @forest from what I understand about SE, unregistered users have to provide an email address. Proof-of-ownership of the unregistered account should then be possible via proof-of-ownership of the email address. Of course I don't actually know how strict the SE staff is on these matters...

Comment: In what way is the original private key provided? Do you just publicly reveal it?